# Why do i keep getting a weird output in c++

Tags: c++

```
{
int x, a;
cout << "Please enter the amount of squares" << endl;
cout << "Pick a number between 1 and 10" << endl;
cin >> x;
cout << "Now enter a character" << endl;
cin >> a;
if (x == 1)
    cout <<"\t"<< a << endl;

return 0;
}
```

for example I will type in  "a" as my character and the output will be -85993640
I originally had char1 instead of a, I also tried putting "char" next to "a" and char1

Comment: You made `a` an `int`, not a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Store the value that you need into a char variable instead of an Integer variable, as you are asking for character input

```
 {
    char a;
    int x;
    cout << "Please enter the amount of squares" << endl;
    cout << "Pick a number between 1 and 10" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Now enter a character" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    if (x == 1)
        cout <<"\t"<< a << endl;

    return 0;
    }
```